# How to show a grid / table in a tab section that will be displayed in in the admin section of prestashop 1.6.x

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to show a grid or editable table in my tab in the admin section 
I managed to do the module and three tabs are been displayed .In one of the tab i want to show a editable grid i.e in the CHECKS tab  [image]

As shown in the below image,in the chek tab section i want to show a grid

In the constructor of my admin controller of my module () 
ie  in  addhealthcheckconfig\controllers\admin\HealthCheckConfigController.php 
 I am setting the field options to populate the tab ,below is my code:

```
$this->fields_options = array(
   'appearance' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Manage  your Health Check '),
    'icon' => 'icon-html5',
    'tabs' => array(
        'TAB1' => $this->l('SUPPORT_GROUPS'),
        'TAB2' => $this->l('CHECKS'),
        'TAB3' => $this->l('REPORT RECIPIENTS'),
        ),
    'fields' => array(
        'SUPPORT_GROUPS' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('SUPPORT GROUPS'),
        'hint' => $this->l('Manage  your Support Groups here'),
        'type' => 'fields_list',
        'name' => 'PS_LOGO',          
        'tab' => 'TAB1'
       ),
    'CHECKS' => array(
     'title' => $this->l('LIST OF AVAILABLE CHECKS '),
     'hint' => $this->l('List of Available checks will be displayed here !!'),
     'type' => 'text',
     'list' =>  $this->fields_list = array(
            'code' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('code'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'remove_onclick' => true,
            'search' => false,
            ),
            'description' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('description'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'remove_onclick' => true,
            'search' => false,
            ),      
            'category' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('category'),
            'align' => 'text-center',
            'remove_onclick' => true,
            'search' => false,
            ),

    ),
        'tab' => 'TAB2'
       ),
         'REPORT_RECIPIENTS' => array(
         'title' => $this->l('REPORT RECIPIENTS '),
         'hint' => $this->l('List of Available checks will be displayed here !!'),
         'tab' => 'TAB3'
       ),

 ) ));
```

In the TAB2 Section i am not sure what i need to put in the 'type' section , I tried with list , but yet I can not achieve what I am trying to do , also i am not sure  how to assign the $this->fields_list to that type correctly

How to achieve this  editable db grid in my tab ?